# Linux process allocated memory usage

Tags: c++, linux, memory, valgrind

how can I measure memory consumed by process? process quits really quickly so utilities like top are useless. I tried using massif by valgrind, but it measures only memory allocated via malloc/new + stack, and not static variables for example. --pages-as-heap doesn't help as well because it shows mapped memory as well.

Comment: Look here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21836/how-to-find-out-total-memory-resource-usage-with-ps

Comment: didn't you read the question? I cannot use ps, process terminates quickly

Comment: Hey Jani, did my answer below work out for you? I'd really like to know if you need more help.

Comment: thanks for trying to help Jacob, what I actually did was added system() call at the end of main() which did ps and exported it to file.

Comment: @JaniBaramidze haha, I didn't realize you had the source to the program you were running. I thought you were doing pure black-box analysis. Yeah, system() would definitely do the job :)

Answer (score 1):

Something that might work for you is using a script that will repeatedly run 'ps' immediately after your program starts. I've written up the following script that should work for your purposes, just replace the variables at the top with your specific details. It currently runs 'netstat' in the background (notice the & symbol) and samples the memory 10 times with 0.1 second intervals between the samples, writing the results of the memory checking to a file as it goes. I've run this on cygwin and it works (minus the -o rss,vsz parameters), I don't have access to a linux machine at the moment but it should be simple to adapt if for some reason it doesn't immediately work.

```
#! /bin/bash

saveFileName=saveFile.txt
userName=jacob
programName=netstat
numberOfSamples="10"
delayBetweenSamples="0.1"
saveFileName=saveFile

i="0"
$programName &
while [ $i -lt $numberOfSamples ]
do
ps -u $userName -o rss,vsz | grep $programName >> $saveFileName
i=$[$i+1]
sleep $delayBetweenSamples
done
```

If your program completes so fast that the delay between executing it and running ps in the script is too long you might consider running your program with a delay and using a very high sample frequency to try and catch it. You can do that by using 'sleep' and two ampersands like `sleep 2 && netstat` . That will wait 2 seconds and then run netstat.

If none of this sounds good to you, perhaps try running your program within a debugger. I believe *gdb* has some memory tracking options you could look into.